# high volume database choice for php

Tags: facebook, search, optimization, yii

I am about to develop website using YII framework. But i am not quite sure about which database i should use.

Generally insertion and selection would be there in a website. Data would be come from different relational tables as i will have more than 50 filters so that user can see what ever database they want to see.

Here is the example of website. http://property.sulekha.com/

I want to design something like this.

which new concept i can use for the optimization, for better performance.

I have few concept in my mind which i am supposing to use.

1) MemCache
2) HipHop PHP
3) Doctorin ORM

I am just wondering how facebook search is working, are they using any advance tool for search??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook architecture is a fascinating one, and you shouldn't try to copy it, because you don't need it, and as we all know, premature optimization is the devil.

scaling issues are not something you prepare for, unless you're working for an enterprise and know first hand that you'll recieve huge amounts of traffic from day 1, like the new mega.

if you're talking about a large de-normalized table, which sounds so by applying up-to 50 filters, maybe you should consider a NoSQL solution, like mongoDB.

from what I know about facebook search, is that the servers are clustered, and are basically pointers to the "real" data, which means that alot of their data isn't a physical one, but as I said, unless you plan on sporting 1 billion users - that's over your head as of now.

good luck

Comment: I know architecture of facebook is very fascinating one and i just want to use the way they are optimizing the website. few concepts i guess it would remain same for every website. It is easy to handle millions of records in mongoDB??? what do you mean by "data isn't physical"